# How to deal with the error "control may reach end of non void function"?

Tags: c, function, palindrome

So here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int PON(int x)
{
int temp,reverse=0;
temp=x;
while (temp!=0) {
    reverse=reverse*10;
    reverse=reverse+(temp%10);
    temp=temp/10;

}
if (x==reverse) {
    printf("It's Palindrome\n");
    return 0;}
else
{printf("It's not Palindrome\n");
    return 1;}
}

int MP(int x)
{
    int a=1;
    if (PON(x==1)) {
        if (PON(x-a)==0) {
            return x-a;
        }
       else if (PON(x+a)==0)
           return x+a;
        else
            while ((PON(x-a)==1)&& (PON(x+a==1)))
                a++;
        if (PON(x-a)==0) {
            return x-a;
        }
        if (PON(x+a)==0)
            return x+a;
            }








    else
        return x;

}


int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int q;
    printf("How many numbers is there ?");
    scanf("%d",&q);
    for (int i=0; i!=q; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        PON(arr[i]);

    }








    return 0;
}
```

Its suppose to get the number of numbers in an array and if they are not palindrome , turn them to the nearest palindrome number ...
Doesn't matter how I re-write my MP function it still gives the "control may reach end of non void function" error ...
if anybody knows how this error can be Debugged please don't hesitate 
Thank you all

Note:I didn't finish my program as I was stuck with the error

So I fixed my problem and my program looks like this now , Thank you everybody !

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



int PON(int x)
{
int temp,reverse=0;
temp=x;
while (temp!=0) {
    reverse=reverse*10;
    reverse=reverse+(temp%10);
    temp=temp/10;

}
if (x==reverse) {

    return 0;}
else

    return 1;}


int MP(int x)
{
    int a=1,ret=-1;
    if (PON(x)==1) {
            if (PON(x-a)==0) {
                ret = x-a;}

            else if (PON(x+a)==0)
                ret= x+a;
            else
                while ((PON(x-a)==1)&& (PON(x+a)==1))
                {a++;
                    if (PON(x-a)==0) {
                        ret= x-a;
                            }
                    if (PON(x+a)==0)
                        ret= x+a;}
                            }








    else
    {ret = x;}
    return ret;

}


int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int q;
    printf("How many numbers is there ?");
    scanf("%d",&q);
    for (int i=0; i!=q; i++) {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);}

    for (int i=0; i!=q; i++) {
        printf("%d \t",MP(arr[i]));
    }






    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: No need to debug, but just to fix! Don't even think about running the code before.

Comment: The message means there are situations when the function completes without returning a value.

Comment: What about if I input 1000000?

Comment: One big problem is poor text formatting. Hard to follow.

Comment: Well, I don't really agree with closing this question. The OP is obviously a novice programmer, and even though his code is obviously not a MCVE, it's still having serious issues, one of which is actually the poor formatting and indentation of his code. he (and future readers) shall take care of. So I will vote for reopening once it will get the fifth closing vote!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your MP function is like this:

```
int MP(int x)
{
    int a=1;
    if (PON(x==1)) {
       /* bunch of stuff here, return not guaranteed */
    } else
       return x;
}
```

You need to make sure that the "if" case reaches a return statement.

Comment: I don't get it but all the sub ifs have a return value
I don't really know in what condition it wouldn't return anything

Comment: @AmirSepehri: If you properly and consistently indented your code you'd see very easily.

Comment: @Amir Just follow the path of the `if/else` statements. There is a path that leads to the bottom of the function without excecuting a `return` statement.  The final `if` within the first `if` block contains no `else`.  Right after `if (PON(x+a)==0)`.  So if control reaches that point, and the condition is false, you will fall through to the bottom of the function.  It could not be more obvious.

Comment: @AmirSepehri well, look at my answer, I tried to show you what your code does, and how it can reach the end of your function without going through a return statement. And BTW, I'm also highlighting a typo and beware of infinite loops!

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is warning you about possible reach of the end of non-void function
because there's a possibility that it might happen, and lead to undefined situation
the compiler doesn't know what to do!

```
int MP(int x) {
    int a=1;
    if (PON(x==1)) {
        if (PON(x-a)==0) {
            return x-a;
        } else if (PON(x+a)==0) {
            return x+a;
        } else {
            while ((PON(x-a)==1)&& (PON(x+a==1))) {
                a++;
            }
        }
        if (PON(x-a)==0) {
            return x-a;
        }
        if (PON(x+a)==0) {
            return x+a;
        }
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}
```

considering that the following conditions are met:

```
PON(x==1) → returns true
PON(x-a)==0 → returns false
PON(x+a)==0 → returns false
```

that in both before and after the `while` loop in the `else` part of your first
conditional, then your code will reach no return statement. Basically what it will
execute will be:

```
int a=1;
PON(x==1) // true
PON(x-a)==0 // false
PON(x+a)==0 // false
while ((PON(x-a)==1)&& (PON(x+a==1))) {
    a++;
}
PON(x-a)==0 // false
PON(x+a)==0 // false
// end of function
```

so within your full code, this would lead to the path shown by the comments below:

```
int MP(int x) {
    int a=1; // ...................................... ①
    if (PON(x==1)) { // .............................. ②
        if (PON(x-a)==0) { // ........................ ③
            return x-a;
        } else if (PON(x+a)==0) { // ................. ④
            return x+a;
        } else { // ............................... // ⑤
            while ((PON(x-a)==1)&& (PON(x+a==1))) { // ⑥
                a++; // ........................... // ⑦
            }
        }
        if (PON(x-a)==0) { // ..................... // ⑧
            return x-a;
        }
        if (PON(x+a)==0) { // ..................... // ⑨
            return x+a;
        }
        // this end of block is being reached ..... // ⑩
    } else {
        return x;
    }
    // the end of the function is being reached ... // ⑪
    // and there's been no return statement on the path to it!
}
```

so a way to handle that would be to set a variable `ret` at the start of your function
assigning it to a default value (even if it's an impossible value to be checked in case
of an error) and assign each of your result with that variable. Your code would then
look like:

```
int MP(int x) {
    int a=1;
    int ret=-1; // let's consider this is an impossible and unwanted value
    if (PON(x==1)) {
        if (PON(x-a)==0) {
            ret = x-a;
        } else if (PON(x+a)==0) {
            ret = x+a;
        } else {
            while ((PON(x-a)==1)&& (PON(x+a==1))) {
                a++;
            }
            if (PON(x-a)==0) {
                ret = x-a;
            }
            if (PON(x+a)==0) {
                ret = x+a;
            }
        }
    } else {
        ret = x;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Though, even though I did not analyse your code in depth, I'm wondering if it actually
makes sense. Because if the first `PON(x-a)==0` and `PON(x+a)==0` returns false, and
then you change a so that `PON(x-a)==1` **AND** `PON(x+a)==1`, then the following
`PON(x-a)==0` and `PON(x+a)==0` cannot be true, as you just set them both up to `1`!

---

BTW, beware that your code has several typos, in how you're calling `PON()`. Sometimes you call it with an `int` argument, other times you're calling it with a `bool` argument, here they are in order of your code:

```
PON(x==1)
PON(x-a)==0
PON(x+a)==0
PON(x-a)==1
PON(x+a==1)
PON(x-a)
PON(x+a)
```

As you've defined `PON()` to take an `int` argument, you should fix your typos so it becomes:

```
PON(x==1) → PON(x)==1
PON(x+a==1) → PON(x+a)==1
```

---

as a side comment, as @weather-vane told, you should make sure to format and indent properly your code to make it easier for others to read… and that "others" might be you in six months! Good formatting also help catch early typical errors, like a missing block around two lines within an `if`…

HTH

Comment: I think the missing `return` is at your comment `10`.

Comment: @weatherVane well, that depends on what the OP wants to do. And I don't believe a return is *necessary* at position ⑩ — even though it's *sufficient* to fix the issue, though every code path need to end with a return, however the OP considers what's the most efficient way to achieve that.

Comment: I agree, the intention is unclear, whether at that point a default value needs to be returned, or a specific value. I originally commented about unnecessary `else` clauses cluttering the code after a conditional `return`, sometimes that is true, but unsure whether the tests here are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Well I suggested _one_ way to fix this, and it's up to the OP to find the best way. I also believe both while loops (within `PON()` and `MP()`) might never finish depending on given arguments, and the OP's code should protect from those special cases.

Comment: I did what you said about using a variable and at end returning it ...
I also fixed the typos and I must say that my program works now
Thanks for your help

Comment: ok! great, now make sure you fix your `PON()` calling typos, and also take a good time to think whether both loops within `PON()` and `MP()` will _never_ get stuck in infinite looping!

Comment: @AmirSpehri, BTW, if an answer helped you out, please think about accepting it, and even +1 it! ;-)

Answer (score -2):

In the function,

```
PON()
```

in the if..else write the result to a variable, and have a **single** return statement.

I think that is what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: No, this is wrong. The problem is in `MP`.  The compiler will not complain about two returns in an `if/else`.